# (jQuery) Select element into TD and filter values with only digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexof

I have a table with a lot td ".numbers" like this:

```
<tr><td class="numbers">12345</td></tr>
<tr><td class="numbers">6789</td></tr>
<tr><td class="numbers">123%</td></tr>
```

I need to select only TD values without "%" and other chars.
**Note**: i cannot remove class "numbers" because is automatically generated.

This is not working:

```
$.each($(".numbers"), function( index, value ) {
    if ($(".numbers").text().indexOf("%")<0) {
    //do stuff
    }
}
```

How can i select td value and filter with indexOf ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For getting td elements that have numeric value in it:

```
$(".numbers").filter(function(){
     return $.isNumeric($(this).text());  
});
```

Comment: This is a good solution for simple char but i guess the question should be `select TD with only numeric chars`, following this statement in question: `values without "%" and other chars`

Comment: @A.Wolff: thanks for pointing out. got confused at part without % :)